# Performance Issue - C# Encryption Method

Tags: performance, loops, encryption, vector, key

I'm facing a huge performance issue, when execute an encryption method. I've written the below code to encrypt a text. When call the method in the code through loop, the execution time was huge as shown below.

```
Record(s)       Time
----------------------
1             0.1 sec
5000          2.8 mins
50,000        28 mins
```

If I remove the remove the `KEY` and `VECTOR(IV)` then the execution time come down to `2` seconds for `50,000` records but, decryption triggers error for key and vector. Can anyone help me out on this.

**Code:**

```cs
public string EncrStng(string tmpText)
 {
 byte[] bytesBuff = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(tmpText);
 using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
  {
  Rfc2898DeriveBytes crypto = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(keyF, salt1, 1000);
  aes.Key = crypto.GetBytes(32);
  aes.IV = crypto.GetBytes(16);
  using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
   using (CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream,aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
    cStream.Write(bytesBuff, 0, bytesBuff.Length);
    cStream.Close();<br>  }<br> inText = Convert.ToBase64String(mStream.ToArray());
    }
   }
  return inText;
  }
```

Thanks,
anand

Comment: I guess it's the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` that takes a long time. You can optimise this by simpling reusing the objects instead of creating new ones at each invocation.

Comment: As Margaret has correctly identified, the performance issue is due to your use of PBKDF2.  You would be safe to instead use the same key for encryption and just generate a new random IV for each record.  This should improve performance massively.